# Position of divs with css

Tags: html, css, position

I want to know if its possible to made appear the main content to the left and the header to the right BUT the HTML is like that

```
<div id="header" style="float:right; height:1000px; width:60%;">
   head
</div>
<div id='main' style ="float:left; height:1000px; width: 40%;">
   main
</div>
```

I already try that but it doesnt work

By the way, the header absolutely needs to be first.

Thank you

Comment: The content already is on the left with the header on the right http://jsfiddle.net/xYURh/

Comment: Floating them both to the right should achieve this affect. Floating the main one to the left only creates a break.

Comment: what do you mean by header must be first? do you mean top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGNGK/) everything is working as you needed. But I would add after these blocks blank div with style clear to further avoid problems with the following blocks.

Or may be you want this? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RGNGK/1/)